# R: Fast Subsetting Large Data Table Conditioned on Key Words in One of the Columns

Tags: r, data.table, subset

The data table I am working with is like

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(2)
dt <- data.table(user=c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 2), rep('c', 4)),
                 type=c(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 3), 
                        sample(LETTERS[1:4], 2),
                        sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4))
                 )
```

which is

```
   user type
1:    a    A
2:    a    C
3:    a    B
4:    b    A
5:    b    C
6:    c    D
7:    c    A
8:    c    B
9:    c    C
```

I'd like to find specific users of types in either `A`, `B` or `C` only. In the example above, user `c` is not qualified because he has `D` in one of his type records. So the desired output should be

```
   user type
1:    a    A
2:    a    C
3:    a    B
4:    b    A
5:    b    C
```

The first method, which is obvious inefficient, comes to my mind is split `dt` with `split(dt, dt$user)` and check if  `grepl` and `nrow` are the same, followed by indexing and `rbindlist`. Since the data table I am actually working with has 10989251 rows, an efficient way to do the subsetting is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouped by 'user', `if` `all` the elements in 'type' have only the first three `LETTERS`, we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`). Here I am using `%chin%` for vector comparison as it is a faster version of `%in%` optimized for `character` vectors.

```
dt[, if(all(type %chin% LETTERS[1:3])) .SD, by = user]
#    user type
#1:    a    A
#2:    a    C
#3:    a    B
#4:    b    A
#5:    b    C
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. How is `chin` different from `in` by the way?

Comment: @Francis According to the description in `?"%chin%"`, it is a faster match of character vectors, which is optimized.

Answer (score 1):

With a classic filter selection:

```
dt[unlist(by(type, user, function(x) !!cumprod(x %in% LETTERS[1:3]))),]
#   user type
#1:    a    A
#2:    a    C
#3:    a    B
#4:    b    A
#5:    b    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Some might find this way less elegant, but it might be faster: find users who have type D, then exclude them. Could skip the unique if there are no or few duplicate user-type pairs.

```
badusers = dt[type=='D',unique(user)];
dt.ABCs = dt[!user %in% badusers,];
```